# Existence of additive non-linear function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

The following question should have a positive answer: it is taken from Example 1.11 of the book "Positive Operators" by Aliprantis and Burkinshaw.

**Question:** Does there exist an additive function $\phi: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ which is not in the form $cx$ for some real $c$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the axiom of choice, yes:

Take a basis $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. Choose two basis vectors $a, b \in B$. Now construct a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear map $\phi$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that maps $a$ to $b$, $b$ to $a$ and any other basis vector in $B$ to itself.

Now $\phi$ is not $\mathbb{R}$-linear (of the form $x \mapsto cx$), since $c$ cannot be $b/a$ and $a/b$ at the same time.