# About the two properties of Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-transformations

We know that to prove a transformation is linear we need to show that

$$T(x_1, y_1)+T(x_2, y_2)=T(x_1+x_2, y_1+y_2)$$

And

$$ kT(x,y) = T(kx, ky)$$

But I can’t think of a transformation which satisfies the first condition but not the second one? Does anyone know one example of this??

Comment: You are looking for a "non-linear additive function". This could be of interest to you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2377638/additive-function-t-mathbbr-rightarrow-mathbbr-that-is-not-linear. Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132215/a-real-function-which-is-additive-but-not-homogenous and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1847606/existence-of-additive-non-linear-function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A real function which is additive but not homogenous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132215/a-real-function-which-is-additive-but-not-homogenous)

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that there are maps $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ but $f$ is not of the form $cx$ where $c$ is a constant. Such a map cannot satisfy the equation $f(kx)=kf(x)$ and $T(x,y)=(f(x),f(y))$ gives a map with the required properties.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a nonzero rational number $r$; now choose a set $\mathcal{B}$ so $\mathcal{B}\cup \{r\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}$.    Now define $T(r) = 1$ and $T$ is 0 on $\mathcal{B}$.  WE can extend $T$ linearly to all of $\mathbb{R}$.  It is the ugly beast you seek.